# look for most matching word

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

I have a table with Tags (words). Each time I want to add a new item (word) to the table, I want to first see words that look the most like the word I am entering, so I could come realize I already have a word in the table that looks like it.

Kind of like using the match() function in Mysql, but I don't want a score of how many words are corresponding. But a score of within a word, how many characters are corresponding.

So something like:  `select * from tags order by look_a_like_score(@newword)`

But is there such a function like look_a_like_score() ?

Example, I already have in table:

> Restaurant
>
> Elevator
>
> Swimming pool
>
> Wifi

Now I want to add:

> Free swimmer facilities

What I would like to have now is a list with 'Swimming pool' on top, because the part 'swimm' is most matching.

Can you help me do this?

PS. I collect the entire table into PHP and then put them into an array. So a PHP approach is also welcome.

Comment: `Swimming pool` and `Free swimmer facilities` are most matching, because both have the `swimm` part. So if anythink, I would give it a score of 5 for having 5 matching characters. Anything more/less fancy is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MySQL side you have soundex, not really working good as I like.
You may want to implement a MySQL module to use levenshtein (you'll need to compile in C either).

On PHP side you have levenshtein() available which is quite decent to have similarity score

You may use too:

soundex() - Calculate the soundex key of a string

similar_text() - Calculate the similarity between two strings

metaphone() - Calculate the metaphone key of a string

Check the manual to know how to use them

Comment: I'm not familiar with levenshtein. But I can already say soundex is not what I'm looking for. I will directly look in similar_text() in php though. Who knows... maybe that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Looking at Levenshtein, it looks a bit like what I want. I'm wondering why you changed your answer from 'use levenshtein' into 'compile in c'. Isn't levenshtein directly usable in mysql?

Comment: If you work with words, levenshtein() will surely be much better, similar_text() is working better for long texts (however extremely slower than levenshtein by construction of the algorithm)

Comment: levenshtein is directly usable in Postgresql, but never saw it in MySQL natively (am i wrong ?) I always had to implement it with a C external function

Comment: So Levenshtein is faster? I think I'll go PHP and use that one then... Thanks

Comment: Hmm. I was just tipped by a collegue: `SELECT ..., MATCH(tag) AGAINST(@newTag IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance ... ORDER BY relevance DESC` also works !

Comment: Yep, match does work. Just be carefull to one thing: match is more to give a relevance of a word (or some) into a text. match may work bad when you search a word into a word. match does not search for similar text (with mistakes for instance), only exact match

Answer (score 0):

You can look here [here](https://github.com/jmcejuela/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF) for an implementation of the [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) formula this is good for finding the edit distance between to string.

Other things that might work out for you is using soundex or possibly [double metaphone](http://www.atomodo.com/code/double-metaphone/metaphone.sql/view) to do "Sounds like" matches.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function.  But, you can do this with some SQL.  Let me assume that @newtag contains your new tag and that you have a `numbers` table.  You can do something like this:

```
select t.tag, max(len) as biggestmatch
from (select concat('%', substr(@newtag, n1.n, n2.n), '%') as pat,
             n1.n as start, n2.n as len
      from numbers n1 cross join
           numbers n2
      where n1.n <= length(@newtag) and n1+n2 <= length(@newtag)
     ) patterns join
     tags t
     on t.tag like patterns.pat
group by t.tag
order by max(len)
limit 1  /* you only need this if you want the best one */
```

I'm not promising that this will perform particularly well.  But for a handful of tags and strings that are not too long, it might suit your purposes.